# How to Fetch date and Check-box data in PHP CRUD Edit operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new in PHP. I have a web form which i use to store data in Mysql. I use jQuery to display current date in my form. After that on a php page i display that data and here is the option of edit that data. Using CRUD operation i perform that job. When user click on edit button all data against that id fetched from db and display on web form. I also use jQuery to display current date in my `edit.php`. Now problem is that when user click on edit button date and checkbox data could not fetched properly from db.

E.g I store data on 30/06/2015 and also check the check box but when I click on edit button all fields data will be displayed but check box is unchecked and date is also changed in current date due to my jQuery.

Here are my code files:

**form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Letter Form </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="formaction.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" > 
 <table border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="500px">
      <tr>
        <td class="DivSubHeaderCellTop"  colspan="6">Letters</td>
</tr> <tr><td>  </td>  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">File Name </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="file_name" type="text" id="file_name" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
      <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Referance #</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"><input name="ref_no" type="text" id="ref_no" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="4"></td>
 <td class="DivCellText" width="80px"></td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">To - Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="to_name" type="text" id="to_name" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
<td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Confidential</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" id="confidential"   />
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="designation" type="text" id="designation" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Date :</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
            <input name="date" type="text" id="date" />  
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" >&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Solutation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='solutation' id='solutation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' >
    <option value='Others' >[--Others--]</option>
    <option value='Dear Sir' >Dear Sir</option>
    <option value='Madam' >Madam</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entity</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="entity" type="text" id="entity" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <input name="txtSolutation" type="text" id="txtSolutation" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_1" type="text" id="add_1" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Thank You.</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" ><input name="thank_you" type="text" id="thank_you" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_2" type="text" id="add_2" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Yours truly</td>
         <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
    <select name='yours_truly' id='yours_truly' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%' >
    <option value='1' >Yours truly</option>
    <option value='2' >Regards</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Add-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="add_3" type="text" id="add_3" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Signature-Name</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >

    <select name='sign_name'  id='sign_name' size='1' style='width:95%'> 
        <option value='1' >Adnan Afaq</option>
        <option value='2' >Muhammad Shahzad Saleem</option>
        <option value='3' >Adnan Dilawar</option>
        <option value='4' >Rana Muhammad Nadeem</option>
        <option value='5' >Jhangeer Hanif</option>
    </select>
    </td> </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;City</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" colspan="3"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">S-Designation</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <select name='s_designation' id='s_designation' size='1' STYLE='width: 95%'>
    <option value='1' >Managing Director</option>
    <option value='2' >Chief Operating Officer</option>
    <option value='3' >Manager Ratings</option>
    <option value='4' >Unit Head Ratings</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-1</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_1" type="text" id="heading_line_1" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"  maxlength="55"/>
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Encl: Line-1</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_1" type="text" id="encl_line_1" value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-2</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_2" type="text" id="heading_line_2" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-2</td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="200px" >
     <input name="encl_line_2" type="text" id="encl_line_2" value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Heading Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="480px" colspan="3"><input name="heading_line_3" type="text" id="heading_line_3" 
    value="" class="inputRemarks"    maxlength="55" />
    </td>
     <td class="DivCellText" width="80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line-3</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
         <input name="encl_line_3" type="text" id="encl_line_3" value="" class="inputRemarks"  />
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr ><td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr ><td colspan="6">
 <table  border="0" class="DivTableBorder" width="829">
 <tr>
<td class="DivCellText" colspan="4">
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="text" name="text" style="font-size:14px;" ></textarea> </td>
<!-- <td class="DivCellText" colspan="2"><br/>
  <br/>
        <br/><br/>
    <input name="addit" id="addit" type="button" value="  Add  " onclick="AddForm();" />    
</td>-->
 </tr>
<tr>
<td width="9">
</td>
<!--<td width="73" colspan="6" ><button type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button> </td> -->
<td width="100"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Copy" class="blueButton"></input></td>
<td width="100" ><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="blueButton"  /> </td>
<td width="600">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="blueButton"></input>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done myself

For check box i change

```
<td class="DivCellText" width="80px">Confidential</td>
    <td class="DivCellText" width="200px">
    <?php if($confidential == "on"){ ?>
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="confidential" value="on"  />
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <input name="confidential" type="checkbox" id="confidential" value="on"  />
    <?php } ?>
```

and for date i change my jquery

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).datepicker();
});   

</script>
```